# What's inside the stack?

Tags: c, x86, stack, low-level

If I run a program, just like

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *env[]) {
  printf("My references are at %p, %p, %p\n", &argc, &argv, &env);
}
```

We can see that those regions are actually in the stack.
But what else is there? If we ran a loop through all the values in Linux 3.5.3 (for example, until segfault) we can see some weird numbers, and kind of two regions, separated by a bunch of zeros, maybe to try to prevent overwriting the environment variables accidentally.

Anyway, in the first region there must be a lot of numbers, such as all the frames for each function call.

How could we distinguish the end of each frame, where the parameters are, where the canary if the compiler added one, return address, CPU status and such?

Comment: Can we keep the comments on topic here. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The contents of the stack are basically:

- Whatever the OS passes to the program.
- Call frames (also called stack frames, activation areas, ...)

What does the OS pass to the program? A typical *nix will pass the environment, arguments to the program, possibly some auxiliary information, and pointers to them to be passed to `main()`.

In Linux, you'll see:

- a NULL
- the filename for the program.
- environment strings
- argument strings (including `argv[0]`)
- padding full of zeros
- the `auxv` array, used to pass information from the kernel to the program
- pointers to environment strings, ended by a NULL pointer
- pointers to argument strings, ended by a NULL pointer
- `argc`

Then, below that are stack frames, which contain:

- arguments
- the return address
- possibly the old value of the frame pointer
- possibly a canary
- local variables
- some padding, for alignment purposes

How do you know which is which in each stack frame? The compiler knows, so it just treats its location in the stack frame appropriately. Debuggers can use annotations for each function in the form of debug info, if available. Otherwise, if there is a frame pointer, you can identify things relative to it: local variables are below the frame pointer, arguments are above the stack pointer. Otherwise, you must use heuristics, things that look like code addresses are probably code addresses, but sometimes this results in incorrect and annoying stack traces.

Answer (score 5):

Without some knowledge of the overlay, you only see bits, or numbers.  While some of the regions are subject to machine specifics, a large number of the details are pretty standard.

If you didn't move too far outside of a nested routine, you are probably looking at [the call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) portion of memory.  With some generally considered "unsafe" C, you can write up fun functions that access function variables a few "calls" above, even if those variables were not "passed" to the function as written in the source code.

The call stack is a good place to start, as 3rd party libraries must be callable by programs that aren't even written yet.  As such, it is fairly standardized.

Stepping outside of your process memory boundaries will give you the dreaded Segmentation violation, as memory fencing will detect an attempt to access non-authorized memory by the process.  Malloc does a little more than "just" return a pointer, on systems with memory segmentation features, it also "marks" the memory accessible to that process and checks all memory accesses that the process assignments are not being violated.

If you keep following this path, sooner or later, you'll get an interest in either the kernel or the object format.  It's much easier to investigate one way of how things are done with Linux, where the source code is available.  Having the source code allows you to not reverse-engineer the data structures by looking at their binaries.  When starting out, the hard part will be learning how to find the right headers.  Later it will be learning how to poke around and possibly change stuff that under non-tinkering conditions you probably shouldn't be changing.

PS. You might consider this memory "the stack" but after a while, you'll see that really it's just a large slab of accessible memory, with one portion of it being considered the stack...

Comment: So, do you say that everything from &first_argument upwards could be *not just* the stack? What's *after* the call stack? Or, how should we call it?

Comment: If you keep walking around in the memory, assuming you don't segfault and the OS assigned a continuous memory range for the program (which is easier to monitor than a bunch of chunks), you might run into the heap.  Additionally some implementations store even more data, to aid debuggers or as communication channels between the OS and the process.

Comment: Note that pointer access to the memory, and a little knowledge can have subroutines do stuff that the language doesn't promote.  That's why Java ditched pointers for references, to prevent access / modification of private variables, etc.

Comment: While some operating systems may zero memory before loading programs into it don't forget that the C library is likely to call a whole slew of initialization subroutines before calling main(). So even your starting stack is likely to have been cluttered up. Get gets worse in C++ where the application initialization can happen before main() is called.

Comment: I don't think it should be the heap, for I had no more code than #include <stdio.h> and using printf(3), so that would be still stack memory. is the place where *argv[] and *env[] stored yet the stack? Then why so much room until the call stack if the stack will grow in the opposite direction?

Answer (score 3):

The content of the stack will vary depending on the architecture [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface), the compiler, and probably various compiler settings and options.

A good place to start is the published ABI for your target architecture, then check that your particular compiler conforms to that standard.  Ultimately you could analyse the assembler output of the compiler or observe the instruction level operation in your debugger.

Remember also that a compiler need not initialise the stack, and will certainly not "clear it down", when it has finished with it, so when it is allocated to a process or thread, it might contain any value - even at power-on, SDRAM for example will not contain any specific or predictable value, if the physical RAM address has been previously used by another process since power on or even an earlier called function in the same process, the content will have whatever that process left in it.  So just looking at the raw stack does not tell you much.

Commonly a generic stack frame may contain the address that control will jump to when the function returns, the values of all the parameters passed, and the value of all auto local variables in the function.  However the ARM ABI for example passes the first four arguments to a function in registers R0 to R3, and holds the return value of the *leaf* function in the LR register, so it is not as simple in all cases as the "typical" implementation I have suggested.

Comment: Well, we can say at least that everything on the stack *above* the current stack frame will be sanitized, because otherwise it would be just nonsense. And anyway anything above that may or may not even be addressed to the current process, so it wouldn't be correct to always say that we can look at it, because there may be no physical mapping for particular address yet.

Comment: @ssice:  Yes of course, there is a distinction between the stack itself, which is entirely meaningful and variable in size and the *stack space* - the space in which the stack grows and shrinks.  That distinction is not clear in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The details are very dependent on your environment. The operating system generally defines an ABI, but that's in fact only enforced for syscalls.

Each language (and each compiler even if they compile the same language) in fact may do some things differently.

However there is some sort of system-wide convention, at least in the sense of interfacing with dynamically loaded libraries.

Yet, details vary a lot.

A very simple "primer" could be http://kernelnewbies.org/ABI

A very detailed and complete specification you could look at to get an idea of the level of complexity and details that are involved in defining an ABI is "System V Application Binary Interface AMD64 Architecture Processor Supplement" http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf